# sed find and replace html tag

Tags: sed, find, replace, html

I need find and replace in a md file (plain text)

```
<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>
```

with this:

```
[&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}
```

I tried many times, f.e.

```
sed -i -e 's/\(<span class=\"symbol\">\)&#58771;\(<\/span>\)/\[/&#58771;\]/\{custom-style=\"symbol\"\}/g'myfile.md
```

or

```
sed -i -e "s#<span class=\"symbol\">&#58771;</span>#[&#58771;]{custom-style=\"symbol\"}#g" "Dignità umana e bioetica".md
```

but I get always an error message, like

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown option to `s'
```

**This** seems work (no error message):

```
sed -i -e "s@<span class=\"symbol\">&#58771;</span>@[&#58771;]{custom-style=\"symbol\"}@g" myfile.md
```

but I get this code

```
[<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}
```

The new string is **added**, not replace the old one.

### solved

As you said, this command works

```
sed -i -e 's@<span class="symbol">\&#58771;<\/span>@[\&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}@g'
```

Comment: This works (no error message):    sed -i -e "s@<span class=\"symbol\">&#58771;</span>@[&#58771;]{custom-style=\"symbol\"}@g" myfile.md,    but I get this code    [<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}    The new string is *added*, not *replace* the old one.

Comment: Is your goal to replace the literal `<span ... /span>` with the literal `[&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}`? Why are you using two capturing groups (the `\(...\)`)? (And I suggest you to edit your question instead of adding comments, you will make it more readable).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is my goal. I tried also without \, but not works.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
sed -i -e "s@<span class=\"symbol\">&#58771;</span>@[\&#58771;]{custom-style=\"symbol\"}@g" myfile.md
```

You need to use `\` before `&`, then it will work fine because `&` is special in the replacement text: it means “the whole part of the input that was matched by the pattern”.

From `man sed`:

> s/regexp/replacement/
>
> The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
# echo '<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>' > test 
# sed -i -e 's@<span class="symbol">\&#58771;<\/span>@[\&#58771;]{custom- 
style="symbol"}@g' test
# cat test 
[&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}
```

Comment: In effect **it works** (sed -i -e 's@<span class="symbol">\&#58771;<\/span>@[\&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}@g' myfile.md):  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code you tried.

First, things are easier if you choose a character that shows up nowhere in your text as the delimiter for the `s///` command. Alternatively, you have to escape with a `\` any occurrence of the delimiter in your text.

In your first command,

```sh
sed -i -e 's/\(<span class=\"symbol\">\)&#58771;\(<\/span>\)/\[/&#58771;\]/\{custom-style=\"symbol\"\}/g'myfile.md
```

the error you get is due to the `/` in `[/&#58771;\]`, that is not escaped.

Also, to put a literal `&` in the output text, you have to escape it with a `\` in your replacement expression. Otherwise `&` is interpreted as special and replaced with the matched portion of the pattern space.

To keep things simple, here I removed (possibly?) unnecessary escape characters and a couple of (possibly?) unneeded `/` (from `[/&#58771;\]/\{custom-style=\"symbol\"\}`). I also chose `|` as the delimiter for the `s///` command, since it does not appear in your input text. The command becomes:

```sh
sed -e 's|<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>|[\&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}|g'
```

And this is what it does:

```sh
$ echo '<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>' | sed -e 's|<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>|[\&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}|g'
[&#58771;]{custom-style="symbol"}
```

If the string `&#58771;` is not static and you want to replace `<span class="symbol">` with `[` and `</span>` with `]{custom-style="symbol"}` around it, whatever its value, you can use a capturing group (`()`) and a backreference (here, `\1`):

```sh
sed -e 's|<span class="symbol">\(.*\)</span>|[\1]{custom-style="symbol"}|g'
```

What this command does:

```sh
$ echo '<span class="symbol">whatever is here</span>' | sed -e 's|<span class="symbol">\(.*\)</span>|[\1]{custom-style="symbol"}|g'
[whatever is here]{custom-style="symbol"}
```

Finally, you may generally prefer to use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) around `sed` scripts, to protect them from the shell - parameter expansion triggered by `$`, escaping effects of `\`...

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
echo "<span class="symbol">&#58771;</span>" |awk -F'=|>|<' 'BEGIN { OFS=""; }{ print "["$4"]","{cumtom-style=""\""$3"\"""}"}'
[&#58771;]{cumtom-style="symbol"}
```